# Can I create my own HTML5 attribute?

Tags: jquery, xml, html, xhtml

I have created a navbar with Jquery and HTML5, and for usability I decided to get a variable directly in the HTML like that

```
<nav class="mainNav" breakpoint="768">
```

I saw it is needed to add "data-" before my custom attribute. So the question is, is it valid to process like this, and is there a problem with XHTML/XML ? Is it a problem if the XHTML/XML is not valid ?

Thanks.

Comment: Depends on what you call "a problem" I'd say. One can do a lot of things. Even things considered bad or breaking standards. That does not automatically mean that the universe is going to implode. If you _should_ do that: the clear answer is "no". You will run into derived problems sooner or later. There is a reasons for standards.

Answer (score 4):

No it's not. You can use like `data-breakpoint="768"` but no like `breakpoint="768"`

**NOTE:** It is not only about standards and rules, **HTML parser** will need to work much harder if he deals with something that is not standards compliant.

Comment: Ok thats what I though thx. Yes but it is just an exception, I will not do it everywhere in my HTML !

Answer (score -1):

Well, you "can" go this way. It will make your HTML invalid, but in practice, it's not really a big deal, only purists will complain, and most browser will just render the page normally. Also it's not really clear what you want. Do you just want it to be HTML valid, or also XHTML valid ? XHTML is probably the biggest failure of W3C, so if you just need to make a classic webpage, html5 compliance is more than enough.

However, the "data-" is now in the HTML specifications. So I encourage you to use this. Not only your page will become truly valid, but you'll also be able to use convenience methods like `document.getElementById('myID').dataset.breakpoint` !

[Link to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)

**EDIT** Whatever you do, you can use [The W3C Validator to check error/ get tips](http://validator.w3.org/)

Comment: I don't really know. I am creating my own CSS Framework so I need solid foundations for the future.

Comment: If you need solid foundations, then you should definitely be careful about this. Also, the problem might become harder if you need compatibility with older versions of browsers. But in anycase, I believe you don't need XHTML compliance

Comment: Mmh ok. I will take a look about the XHTML to know if it is or not a big deal. Thanks for the reply